# no clientlets found for response, using the lobo browser

Tags: java, lobo, lobo-cobra

i am using the lobo browser, and when i run the example code, i keep getting the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No clientlets found for response: ClientletResponseImpl[url=http://www.google.com,method=GET,mimeType=text/html,fromCache=false,requestType=PROGRAMMATIC'.

anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when i was trying to embed the FramePanel in my java application.
I think there is a dependency in the code that there will be a directory with name "ext" and the extension jars are present in that directory. "ext" directory should be at the same level as lobo.jar file. This solved my problem.